# What ('70s cop?) movie is this from?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Can you identify this film? You can hear him say "...just what..." at ~0:57 in this [clip](http://vimeo.com/35055590).

[image: Identify this movie]

I guess he's a policeman in a '70s film, and there's a "LT. V..." on the office door window, must be some police lieutenant's office. He sounds American and there's a New York map on the wall (Long Island and Jamaica Bay flanked by yellow-marked Floyd Bennett Field and JFK airport. Central New York and Manhattan are to the west and are not part of this map, which appears to continues east into Long Island and NY state.)

[image: Identify this movie]

And here's another from the same film (~1:02 in the [clip](http://vimeo.com/35055590)) where he again says "...just what...". And again it looks like a police station, and there's a clipboard hanging behind him that says "BCI..." something (could be referring to the [Bureau of Criminal Investigation](http://troopers.ny.gov/criminal_investigation/), "the plainclothes detective branch of the New York State Police").

My guess is these are both from the same scene: he's wearing the same clothes, is in the same dull green police office, and is probably getting more angry repeatedly asking this question.

Comment: I'm off-topic, but isn't this super cut of 'Hello' amazing?

Comment: I've seen this guy so many times in similar roles and he always looks the same! I just can't remember any movies I'm sure he's in. I've looked at alot of 70's era movies like the Dirty Harry's (even though that's San Francisco), Serpico, and some Roy Scheider and Gene Hackman detective movies like French Connection, the Seven-Ups, etc. I just don't see him, but i know he's there.

Comment: This one's driving me nuts too!

Comment: Tip: [Subzin.com](http://www.subzin.com/) may help to confirm or rule out guesses.

Comment: The map is Brooklyn, if that level of extra detail helps. Might not, of course ;o)

Comment: p.s. If anyone's interested in the other sources in that Hello video, I'm compiling a list: http://s1mn.calepin.co/hello.html

Comment: This is driving me nuts.. I'm convinced it's not from the '70s but more in the mid-80s.  I've been searching for hours over the past few days and haven't made any headway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The film is **Shaft (1971)**. That's Charles Cioffi playing Lt Vic Androzzi.

[image]

http://pixhost.me/pictures/1985106

Comment: You can see the first "Just what" in the trailer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiCB2isZcRM (fast forward to 01:48)

Comment: Direct link to [1m48s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiCB2isZcRM&t=1m48s) in that trailer (actually the second "just what"), and here's [both](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=shaft&imdb=67741&q=%22just+what%22&search_sort=Popularity&genre=-1&type=All) in context. Good work, the brothers Whitaker!

Comment: Just looking at his credits - I was on the right track for detectives, but in the wromng genre - TV. But this does explain why I've seen him so much - and I wasn't far off with the San Fransisco angle either. I also had considered Kojak, but one of the movies, rather than the television series. Plus IMDB doesn't provide a picture for him. _Missing_ is a great movie - good incentive to find it. Kudos again.